# Retain cycle Objective C with 3 objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, retain-cycle

I have 3 objects - a ViewController, another VC that is the strong property of the ViewController (call it VC2), and a class called "Checker" that checks to see if an action occurred in VC2. "Checker" is just a class with class methods - no instance methods.

When an action occurs in VC2, it sends an data structure to "Checker" which processes it. I need to send that processed data back to ViewController. I grab the instance of ViewController and send it via method. ViewController takes the processed data and displays it in it's view.

Will this create a retain cycle or any other memory-related problems?

Comment: This depends on your implementation, in particular how you address `ViewController`.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad what do you mean? updated question with what ViewController does with data.

Comment: How do you grab the VC?

Comment: It's part of the storyboard so I grab the already existing instance from the appDelegate.

Comment: Simply pasting the code into your Q, one can make the A more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In respect of your comments, the A is:

Grabbing the already existing object reference ("already existing instance") does not create a retain cycle. Passing a reference to a method does not cause a strong reference by default:

```
{
  …
  [Checker doSomethingWith:vc2.referenceToVC1]; // Passing does not retain
  …
}
```

However, even it would or you copy the instance reference into a strong local var before passing it, the ownership would be a short-timer and resolved automatically by ARC.

```
{
  …
  VC1 vc1 = vc2.referenceToVC1; // strong reference causing ownership, retain
  [Checker doSomethingWith:vc1];
  …
  // vc1 and its strong reference is automatically given up, release 
}
```

This is, because the local var (and potentially the parameter var, which is akin of local var) are *additional* references, but since nothing is referring them, it is no retain *cycle*.

You do not have a retain cycle.